# Is there any limit to detect Estimote beacons from Android App?

Tags: estimote

I've 6 Estimote beacons near to Android Device. And, i installed demo app and in that device showing/detecting only beacons out of 6 beacons (All 6 beacons are with in range only).

So, i want to know that is there any limit to detect beacons from Android device (App)?

Comment: If the demo app is not able to detect the beacon then there is surely some problem in that beacons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limit.

If not all beacons are showing up, then it can be something with the beacons themselves. You might want to contact Estimote Customer Support (contact@estimote.com) for help with troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because in that demo app they are listing first fond beacon that is nearest beacon that's why showing only single beacon

**`eg.`**

```
 Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);
```

So you can replace that  0 to number of beacons that is i beacons

**`eg.`**

```
for(int i =0 ; i<list.size();i++){

  Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(i);

}
```

something like this